# Antlr4 and TypeScript: type error when using grammar specific lexer and parser

Tags: typescript, plsql, antlr4

When trying to use the `PlSql` in a basic example as described by the documentation TypeScript reports a type error when using the grammar specific `PlSqlLexer` and `PlSqlParser`.

**This is how the grammar is generated:**

```bash
# clean
rm -rf grammar
mkdir grammar

# download grammar
curl --output grammar/PlSqlLexer.g4 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/sql/plsql/PlSqlLexer.g4
curl --output grammar/PlSqlParser.g4 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/sql/plsql/PlSqlParser.g4

### convert grammar for Typescript
antlr4 -Dlanguage=TypeScript grammar/PlSqlLexer.g4
antlr4 -Dlanguage=TypeScript grammar/PlSqlParser.g4
```

**This is the example code:**

```js
import antlr4 from 'antlr4';
import PlSqlLexer from './grammar/PlSqlLexer';
import PlSqlParser from './grammar/PlSqlParser';

const input = 'select * from dual';
const chars = new antlr4.CharStream(input);
const lexer = new PlSqlLexer(chars);
const tokens = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer); /* type error 1 */
const parser = new PlSqlParser(tokens);
const tree = parser.sql_script();
console.log(tree.toStringTree(null, parser)); /* type error 2 */
```

**type error 1:**

Argument of type 'PlSqlLexer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Lexer'.
Type 'PlSqlLexer' is missing the following properties from type 'Lexer': _input, _interp, text, line, and 18 more.

**type error 2:**

Argument of type 'PlSqlParser' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Parser'.
Type 'PlSqlParser' is missing the following properties from type 'Parser': _input, _ctx, _interp, _errHandler, and 25 more.

Comment: The TypeScript target does not work--it uses "antlr4ts", the Tunnelvision fork. The list of what targets that work for the grammar is in the [desc.xml](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/eba5c4487067292a82cf6b753f33a6b546c7e1df/sql/plsql/desc.xml#L4). I haven't had time to port it yet to the "official" TypeScript Antlr runtime. But, the fact that I don't see the "interpreted" targets such as JS, PHP, or Python in the desc.xml means the grammar is slow.

Comment: 1) Do I understand you correctly: 1.1) Officially he PlSql grammar currently only supports C# and Java? 1.2) antlr4 itself would natively support TypeScript for the PlSql grammar has not yet been ported? 1.3) The PlSql grammar should work with the antlr4ts library? 2) I have also already tried using the antlr4ts library but still get type errors. Would you have a working example on how to use the PlSql grammar with the antlr4ts library? 3) Is there any documentation that I missed ?

Comment: Yes, the plsql/ grammar works only for CSharp and Java. That's what the desc.xml is saying. Yes, the grammar has not been ported to the "official" TS target. It may "work" for the Tunnelvision port at one time, but we don't test non-"official" ports in grammars-v4. I have no idea whether it still does. There's no further "doc" on the TS port. I have it working for JS now, and will have the "official" TS port shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved with the latest revision of the PlSql grammar and now the following example does work as expected:

```js
import * as antlr4 from 'antlr4';
import PlSqlLexer from './grammar/PlSqlLexer';
import PlSqlParser from './grammar/PlSqlParser';

const chars = new antlr4.CharStream('select * from dual;');
const lexer = new PlSqlLexer(chars);
const tokens = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer);
const parser = new PlSqlParser(tokens);
const tree = parser.sql_script();
console.log(tree.toStringTree(null, parser));
```

after generating the grammar with this script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# clean
rm -rf grammar
mkdir grammar

# download grammar
curl --output grammar/PlSqlLexer.g4 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/sql/plsql/PlSqlLexer.g4
curl --output grammar/PlSqlParser.g4 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/sql/plsql/PlSqlParser.g4

### convert grammar for Typescript
antlr4 -Dlanguage=TypeScript grammar/PlSqlLexer.g4
antlr4 -Dlanguage=TypeScript grammar/PlSqlParser.g4

# download Typescript support files
curl --output grammar/PlSqlLexerBase.ts https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/sql/plsql/TypeScript/PlSqlLexerBase.ts
curl --output grammar/PlSqlParserBase.ts https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/sql/plsql/TypeScript/PlSqlParserBase.ts
```